# Shiny - Web Framework for R › how to use an input switch to conditionally group

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

asked this on the shiny google group, w no help yet: I'm struggling with how to pass an input switch to dplyr's group_by_ in the code below.

I bolded the two parts of relevant code in the not-so-MRE below (ie, lines 9:11, and 24).

effectively, if the user selects "daily" in the UI, the resultant grouping should be group_by(year = year(my_date), month = month(my_date), day = day(my_date) in line 24, or remove ANY grouping as the data is already daily.

selecting "monthly", should yield group_by(year = year(my_date), month = month(my_date))

"yearly", should yield group_by(year = year(my_date))

I welcome meta-suggestions/ criticism about how my code/ structures are organized.

Thank you

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dateInput("start", label = "start date", value = "2010-01-01"),
  dateInput("end", label = "end date", value = "2020-01-01"),
  selectInput("grouping_freq", label = "Granularity", 
              choices = list("daily" = 1,"monthly" = 2, "Yearly" = 3), 
              selected = 2), 
  tableOutput("my_table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {  

  df <- reactive({ data_frame(my_date = seq(input$start, input$end, by = 'day')) }) ## 10 years of daily data

  df2 <- reactive({ df() %>% mutate(dummy_data = cumsum(rnorm( nrow( df() ) ))) })

  output$my_table <- renderTable({
    df2() %>% group_by(year = year(my_date), month = month(my_date)) %>% 
      summarise(dummy_data = sum(dummy_data), my_date = as.Date(min(my_date)))
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You can use `do.call` to supply a dynamic list of arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the value chosen in `selectInput` to create a list of formulas that are passed into `group_by_`, the version of `dplyr::group_by` that uses standard evaluation.

```
group_list <- switch(input$grouping_freq,
  list(yr=~year(my_date), mn=~month(my_date), dy=~day(my_date)),
  list(yr=~year(my_date), mn=~month(my_date))
  list(yr=~year(my_date)))
```

or if you prefer if statements,

```
group_list <- if (input$grouping_freq == 1) {
    list(yr=~year(my_date), mn=~month(my_date), dy=~day(my_date))
  } else if (input$grouping_freq == 2) {
    list(yr=~year(my_date), mn=~month(my_date))
  } else if (input$grouping_freq == 3) {
    list(yr=~year(my_date))
  } else {
    list()
  }
```

and then you can pass `group_list` into the `renderTable` expression

```
output$my_table <- renderTable({
  df2() %>% 
    group_by_(.dots=group_list) %>% 
    summarise(dummy_data = sum(dummy_data), my_date = as.Date(min(my_date)))
})
```

I am not sure what you meant by "remove ANY grouping as the data is already daily." but if the data might already be grouped you can use the `ungroup` function to remove any groups before applying the groupings in `group_list`.

**Edit**: Forgot to include `~` in the list elements so that they evaluate correctly.